# Python list of class: variables "aliased", no sub-reference possible

Tags: python, class

I would like to create my own data class to make the code more readable. The problem is that I get an unexpected result when apply the class (e.g. `Myclass`) in a list. Specifically when I perform calculations on the individual members of the list, all members are treated as a single variable; the result in this case equal to the sum of all members. Consider the following example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# create a simple class
class Myclass:

  def __init__(self,mem):
    self.mem = mem
  def __repr__(self):
    return '%d'%self.mem

# simple program: each list item should be unique
if __name__=='__main__':

  # initate array
  nlst = 3
  dlst = [Myclass(0)]*nlst
  ilst = [0]*nlst


  # generate example data
  for i in range(nlst):
    for j in range(nlst)[i:]:
      dlst[i].mem += (i+j)
      ilst[i] += (i+j)

  print 'dlst = ',dlst
  print 'ilst = ',ilst
```

In this example a list `dlst` (length `nlst = 3`) is initiated in which the members are of type `Myclass` and are initiated to zero. A simple addition is then performed in a loop. As a reference a list of integers is included (`ilst`). The result of this example should be:

```
ilst = [3, 5, 4]
```

but for the list of members of the `Myclass` type the result is

```
dlst = [12, 12, 12]
```

I.e. they appear to be the same variable, which value is the sum of the individual members of the list.

Please help.

Comment: Martijn Pieters has it pegged.

A few other helpful notes:
1. Use new-style classes MyClass(object) (if you are in 2.7, at least, which most people use)
2. You are making one instance, then copying it n times ([x]*3 = [x, x, x]).
3. The only reason this works with numbers is that Python handles numbers as constants (i.e., every 2 is actually the SAME 2 and math operations return other such constants).
4. Use xrange instead of range in iterators (for 2.7.  In 3+, range IS xrange).
5. In range/xrange, you can use xrange(start,end) rather than range(len)[start:].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating **one** instance, then copying the reference to that instance `nlst` times:

```
dlst = [Myclass(0)]*nlst
```

This does not create a list of `nlist` instances of `Myclass(0)`; it creates a list of `nlst` references, all pointing to one object.

Use a list comprehension instead:

```
dlst = [Myclass(0) for _ in range(nlst)]
```

In a list comprehension, the expression on the left is re-executed for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

try change:

```
dlst = [Myclass(0)]*nlst
```

to:

```
dlst = [Myclass(0) for i in range(nlst)]
```